# Unexpected result with numpy.dot

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices:

```
>>> a.shape
(100, 3, 1)
>>> b.shape
(100, 3, 3)
```

I'd like to perform a dot product such that my end result is (100, 3, 1). However, currently I receive:

```
>>> c = np.dot(b, a)
>>> c.shape
(100, 3, 100, 1)
```

Could somebody explain what is happening? I'm reading the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and can't figure it out.

**Edit:**

So per the docs (overlooked it):

> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.

And that gives the desired result, but I'm still curious, what is taking place here? What rule of the `np.dot` function is being applied to yield a result of `(100, 3, 100, 1)`?

Comment: Does `np.matmul(b, a)` give you what you want?

Comment: @yatu Yes, but I put that in my edit before you commented (technically I used `b @ a`).

Comment: The behaviour really depends on the dimensions of the input matrices. Check out the docs for cases where the input arrays are ndarrays (last bullet point) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: `dot` does a kind of `outer` product on the leading dimensions.  That's a big reason why `matmul` was added; it treats those dimensions as batches.  `dpt` handling of 3d arrays is so quirky that I haven't tried to understand the exact details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how dot works in your case:

```py
dot(b, a)[i,j,k,m] = sum(b[i,j,:] * a[k,:,m])
```

Your output shape is exactly how the docs specify it:

```py
(b.shape[0], b.shape[1], a.shape[0], a.shape[2])
```

If it's not what you expected, you might be looking for another matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

`dot` will return all the possible products of the matrices stored in the last two dimensions of your arrays. Use `matmul` aka the `@` operator to broadcast the leading dimensions instead of combining them:

```
np.matmul(b, a)
```

Or

```
b @ a
```

The Swiss Army knife of sum-products is `einsum`, so you can use that too:

```
np.einsum('aij,ajk->aik', b, a)
```

Or

```
np.einsum('ajk,aij->aik', a, b)
```